# Displaying images from database using c# .net

Tags: c#, asp.net

recently, I've been developing a website with .NET c# and I've been trying to display images via the imagepath in the db. It is currently working by this line of code.

```
return File(byte array, "image/jpeg");
```

The problem is that by this line of code the layout page is completely ignored as only the image with white background is shown. I need to display the image along with the return view (the image inside the layout of the website).  thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you're not seeing anything is because you can only have one type of response per request; Either a response containing HTML or a response containing the image.

What you need to do in order to serve images via your application is set up a route that you can put in your `<img>` tags as the `src` attribute.

```
<img src="/static/images/123">
```

Your route would listen for requests on the `/static/images/` path and then try to parse the ID number at the end. It could then take that ID number (`123`) and look up the relevant image in your database.

So, to be clear, you'd have at least two requests that occur; First, you serve the request for the page, then you serve subsequent requests for the image(s). These two request handlers do not share the same code.

Finally, if you *really* wanted to "inline" an image as part of the page response, The only way you can "inline" an image into a page is to base64 encode it and set that as as the `src` of an `<img>` tag. This process is slow and bloats your HTML, making it take longer to load.